# Can I work on the bash shell on windows now?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I want ask you about the bash shell on windows ..
can I work on it now?? and how I can run it?

because I try to run bash on CMD and this message appears

```
C:\Users\Pc>bash

Pc@User /cygdrive/c/Users/Pc
$
```

Answer (score 1):

As it looks, you are already running it..
Enter `echo $?`, hit enter and it should return `0`

Answer (score 0):

Someone has installed [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) on your PC for you.

Comment: Not necessarily, although of course quite possible. Cygwin provides not the only bash implementation for Windows.

Comment: @user1934428 I'd be very surprised if the other implementations also took Cygwin's `/cygdrive` prefix.

Comment: Point taken! I missed this part.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and enjoy `bash` and the rest of the tools. I recommend to read a book on the subject.

As already mentioned, `/cygdrive` is prefix used by Cygwin to reference Windows drive letters. E.g. `/cygdrive/c` references drive `C:\`. Cygwin itself is usually installed in `C:\cygwin` or `C:\cygwin64` (64-bit version).

Check the [Cygwin User Guide](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygwin-ug-net.html) for more information.